# What is a good resource for learning to use pthreads with GTK?

Tags: gtk, pthreads

So, just as introduction, I'm something of, as the kids say, a noob. I took CS 1 and 2 in college and (if I remember right) we got as far as recursion, linked lists, binary trees, etc. Nothing about GUI programming or multithreading was covered.

So, now I'm playing around trying to learn C and I've got this idea that I want to write a platform-style game as a goal. I've got a ways to go but, hey, it's good to have something to shoot for.

So, the question is basically this: My understanding is that GTK is event driven, it sits around in gtk_main() and waits for the user to do stuff, then events are handled with callback functions (maybe that's a simplistic understanding but it kinda makes sense in my head, and I've been able to write a couple of simple programs with graphical interfaces thinking of it that way). Anyway, in a platform-style game, stuff needs to be happening even when the user isn't pushing a key or a mouse button. So my thought is that you could still have gtk_main() sitting around waiting for input events and handling them, and then another thread that makes the program do video-gamey stuff while GTK is waiting on the user. In other words, Donkey Kong still needs to throw barrels whether Mario is moving around or not.

A similar question on this site pointed me to [this tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) on multithreading, but I was wondering if there's any information out there specific to applying it with GTK. My Google-fu might be weak but it seems like there isn't much on the internet, and the little information I have found makes it sound like mixing threads and GTK might be kinda dangerous.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand the situation in which one requires multi-threading. GTK's event loop can service platform games perfectly fine because your callbacks are invoked not only on input events, but [also on timeouts](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.35/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add). This feature allows implementing animations, because you can schedule Mario to move several times per second regardless of whether user presses a key.

In other words, as long as your callbacks returns before the time to draw the next frame, *your game will never miss a beat*, all without using threads. Many applications and games which appear perfectly responsive are at their core single-threaded, or are using threads only for specialized tasks.

Multi-threading is complicated with GUI toolkits and requires an experienced professional programmer to get it right. Due to various technical reasons, you must access the toolkit from the same thread. This is [explained in the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html), along with some other gory details. If that's the case, why do so many programs boast with multi-threading, and when is it needed? There are several cases when multi-threading in GUI applications is desired:

1. To leverage the full power of multi-core CPU. The single-thread model can only employ one CPU in total, where current systems tend to have more and more CPUs.

   Ideally you would have a thread pool with as many threads as there are cores on your system. When a CPU-bound calculation is required, a request is pushed to a queue associated with the thread pool, to be picked up by the first free thread in the pool. Whenever a calculation is done, the GUI event loop is notified so that it can display the result.
2. To prevent the "sluggish GUI" syndrome, where slow-executing callbacks make the GUI unresponsive.

   Many callbacks designed to perform a "quick task" before "immediately" returning to main loop end up taking a longer time than expected for reasons that could not be anticipated by the programmer. For example, the dataset originally consisting of a dozen records grows to a hundred thousand. Or, the small XML file that needs to be parsed ends up on network disk that takes forever to access.

   The architecture that prevents GUI sluggishness is very similar to the one described in point #1, except here the number of threads can exceed the number of cores, and *all* non-trivial tasks are considered worthy of handing off to a separate thread. Specifically, the event dispatch thread does no non-trivial processing — it only executes the minimum amount of code needed to receive events and dispatch them to other threads that do the actual work.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses. Timeouts are the detail I think I was missing. I was hoping to not have to go the multithreading route, it does sound like it brings a layer of complexity best suited to a professional, and it doesn't seem like hobby programmers have had trouble making games before. I'll look into the information provided and I think it will get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @user2281387 Yes, timeouts are exactly what you need, and are in fact a standard feature of event-loop-driven systems. The rest of my answer is for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [GThread](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Threads.html) as it's part of GLib anyway), the platform-independent multi-threading module of GLib and GTK+. Basically, you just call `g_thread_create` with a pointer pointing to your function that is going to run in parallel as well as a pointer to data that you want to pass into that function. But you have to take care not to mess with updating the UI by enclosing all GTK+-related calls between `gdk_threads_enter` and `gdk_threads_leave`.